# alter the location of the _build dir Mix uses

Tags: build, elixir, elixir-mix

In the process of building project with Mix I have the req of placing the result of the build in another dir.

Mix normally places the build artefacts in **/project_path/_build**.
I cannot write anything to **/project_path** during the actual build.

Can I change the output dir? Is this something that can be easily adjusted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4e648199f18ee3be8addab82c951b9e2dd82f885/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/new.ex#L286), you can specify a keyword list member `build_path` to override the default `_build` directory.

Example:

```
def project do
    [app: :my_app,
    version: "0.0.1",
    elixir: "~> 1.2",
    build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
    start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
    build_path: "custom_build_dir",
    deps: deps]
end
```